# Error Converting data type nvarchar to float ( ORacle to SQL server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

First of all, I have a MS SQL server 2008 Std. edition on my server and I have a linked server between Oracle and SQL server 2008. I try to take data from Oracle server to SQL server and I have a problem like this:

When I try to convert one column `nvarchar` to `Float` it gives error like this:

> Error Converting data type nvarchar to float.

But when I try to make same job with SQL server 2008 R2 it doesn't give any error and works fine.

I know It caused by Decimal symbol (`.` and `,`) but is there anything to fix this situation and provide it to work on also SQL server 2008 std. edition?

Comment: You need to show the data/value being converted - do you have any?

Comment: If you know it is '`,`' causing the issue, then replace it with '`.`' using `replace` function before converting.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, and @Kaf yes you are right it solves the problem but I suspect that 'replace' function causes performance issue

Comment: "suspect" is a weasel term. Do you mean you have performance profiles indicating that selects statements with a REPLACE() function run *noticeably* slower than statements without them? Or is this just baseless wondering?  Either way this is the price which must be paid for storing numeric data as strings.